# VSCode not hitting breakpoint for test cases

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jestjs

Not sure if anyone has faced this issue before.

I Created an app using 'create-react-app' with VSCode and followed the steps mentioned here for debugging test scripts -

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/debugging-tests#debugging-tests-in-visual-studio-code

The debugger works fine only when the test scripts are directly under /src folder.
If I place any test file under any subfolder of /src then the breakpoints are not hit.

Note that the test scripts are running fine, only problem is debugger is not hitting the breakpoints.

Is it a bug in VSCode or am I missing some configuration?

Highly appreciate any help.